# Problems with wp_list_pages and page hierarchy

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to do something that I'm sure should be really simple with `wp_list_pages`  but I just can't get it to work reliably.

I have a set of pages which all use a custom page template I created, `lesson-plans-page.php`.

I am trying to output a hierarchical (properly nested) menu of all pages that use this template in a sidebar.

Currently there are 5 pages only. One parent page with 4 child pages

However, it only works *hierarchically* if the pages are sorted so that the parent pages is first...
Shouldn't `wp_list_pages` automatically output them hierarchically or am I missing something?

I created the parent page first, so if I sort by `ID` it works.
If I do not sort by anything, it outputs all 5 pages at the same level with the parent page last.
I note that it still knows that the parent has children because of the class it attaches to that `<li>` but the children are not nested in their own `<ul></ul>` below the parent.

This is the actual page structure and names:

```
-Inclusive Learning Through Drama
--Early Stage 1
--Stage 1
--Stage 2
--Stage 3
```

My code is just this (which works but only because of the sort_column.

```
<ul>
    <?php wp_list_pages( array( 
        'post_type' => 'page',
        'meta_key' => '_wp_page_template',
        'meta_value' => 'lesson-plans-page.php',
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'title_li' => '',
        'sort_column' => 'ID',
        'link_before' => '<button class="expand-children"></button>'
        ) ); ?>
</ul>
```

As is, in summary it outputs like this which is what I want
(here I have removed the `<a>` and `<buttons>` tags for simplicity)

```
<ul>
    <li class="page_item_has_children">Inclusive Learning Through Drama
        <ul class=children>
            <li>Early Stage 1</li>
            <li>Stage 1</li>
            <li>Stage 2</li>
            <li>Stage 3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

If I remove the sort_column it outputs like this instead

```
<ul>
    <li>Early Stage 1</li>
    <li>Stage 1</li>
    <li>Stage 2</li>
    <li>Stage 3</li>
    <li class="page_item_has_children">Inclusive Learning Through Drama</li>
</ul>
```

So, my question is: how can I get it to output the html correctly nested without adding some sorting based on a known factor such as ID (which would not work if I'd happened to create them in a different order)?

Other things I tried were to use the WP order attribute on pages but that did not work unless I started the order on the child pages at 1 and with the parent page at 0 which goes against the point of having parent-child relationship. (child page order is independent of parent page order).

The users should be able to create new pages in any order and have them automatically add to the sidebar menu.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Keep page hierarchy in wp\_list\_pages, even if on a child or grandchild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33155726/keep-page-hierarchy-in-wp-list-pages-even-if-on-a-child-or-grandchild)

Comment: Unfortunately that isn't how `wp_list_pages` works by default. See that answer in the question I linked to for a way to do this. Also FYI, `hierarchical` isn't a valid argument for wp_list_pages. There is a `depth` argument but it doesn't work the same way you are trying here either - it takes a value of how many levels of children/grandchildren to get

Comment: @FluffyKitten thanks I will review that link now, but just in response to your comment re the `hierarchical` argument, the docs on `wp_list_pages()` states "See get_pages() for additional arguments.". `hierarchical` is an argument on `get_pages()` - does that not make it a valid argument?

Comment: You're right sorry, I missed the `hierarchical` argument in get_pages.

Comment: @FluffyKitten I'm not seeing how that linked post helps. Their question/problem relates to keeping the hierarchy when on child pages. They are using the `child_of` attribute in relation to the page they are currently on, which is at the core of their issue. 
My use case fetches the same pages irrespective of the current page as it uses meta key/value to fetch them. Also, it _does_ automatically create a nested result, as long as the query has them in the right order - there must be a way to order them by hierarchy surely...

Comment: If I'm missing something in how you see their solution as helping my issue, please do let me know. 
FWIW, it did actually read that post earlier in my research.

Comment: The query needs to know what to sort the pages/posts by. If you can set the menu order for each page then you can use that, but its not a very flexible option. There is no sort option for parent/child so in that case you have to do what they are doing in that answer, but starting with the top level parent. So start with level 1 and get its children, then for each of those you need to get their children etc. Don't forget that these queries are just translated into SQL and there is no way to sort the database query by hierarchy so this is the workaround.

Comment: Yeah ok. Thank for your help. I'll rework it to go through with multiple single depth queries and then fetch children.

Comment: If you have a number of levels then you can create a recursive function that will keep descending through the levels instead of trying to manually code for each one.

Comment: funny you should mention that. I ended up stumbling across the `wp_list_pages()` function after confusing the hell out of myself trying to write a recursive function to do this a few days ago... :-)

Comment: I'm sure there must be examples out there doing this recursively, either using wp_list_pages or get_pages. Try looking on https://wordpress.stackexchange.com too. I'm sure I've even done it myself at some stage but can't find it. If you get stuck, you can ask again here and post your code so we can take a look and help :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I've gone ahead and resolved this using a recursive function and a fair bit of other logic.

It was a lot more complex than anticipated.

The problem with `wp_list_pages` is it must be sorted in the exact order that the parent child relationships exist in order to work. Alternatively, you can run it 1 level at a time but this must be based on a specific given page.. i.e. the page your are on, not just iteratively on each result. This doesn't work in my case because I am creating a menu based on all pages that use a specific template.
The `depth` argument in `wp_list_pages` is also little misleading.. or at least, I misunderstood what it does. It DOES NOT, just fetch the first level if set to 1... it fetches 1 level based on whatever level the first page found is... this isn't helpful in my scenario because I dont know what the first page found is..
For that to work, you need to know what the top most page is first..

Below is my solution which works perfectly.

In summary;

- custom query returns all pages using my template
- results are looped across
- a recursive function iterates down each branch

[results img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYJuC.png)

```
<?php
// this function recursivly loops down each branch
function buildTree(array $page_ids, $parent_page_id = 0, $current_page = 0) {

    $branch = '';

    // loop each page id in the array
    foreach($page_ids as $page_id) {

        // if the looped page's parent matches the parent page passed in, add it to the branch
        if (wp_get_post_parent_id($page_id) == $parent_page_id) {

            // pass each page back in using the current page in the loop as the parent argument to check for grandchildren... etc
            $children = buildTree($page_ids, $page_id, $current_page);
            
            // create html markup for the branch. 
            $branch .= '<li class="' .'page_item_'. $page_id . ' child_of_' . $parent_page_id . ($children !== '' ? ' page_item_has_children':'') . ($page_id == $current_page ? ' current_page_item':'') .'">';
            $branch .= '<a href="'. get_permalink($page_id) .'"' . ($page_id == $current_page ? 'aria-current="page"':'') . '>';
            $branch .= '<button class="expand-children"></button>';
            $branch .= esc_html( get_the_title($page_id) );
            $branch .= '</a>';

            // if children were returned append them inside the <li>
            if ($children) {
                $branch .= $children;
            }

            $branch .= '</li>';
        }

    }

    // if the branch is not empty wrap it in ul tags
    if($branch) {
        $branch = '<ul class="children">' . $branch .'</ul>';
    }
    
    // return the branch
    // will be a nested ul li ul ... list of all children and grandchildren for the parent passed in
    return $branch;
}

// get the ID of the page we on as well as all it's ancestors. 
// Used for CSS purposes to match current page to selected menu item
// Used for JS purposes to expand/collapse appropriatly. 
$current_page_id = get_the_id();
$current_page_ancestors = get_post_ancestors( $current_page_id );

// Query pages using the lesson plan template
$query = new WP_Query(
    array(
        'post_type' => 'page',
        'meta_key' => '_wp_page_template',
        'meta_value' => 'lesson-plans-page.php',
        'posts_per_page'=> -1,
        'orderby'  => 'menu_order',
        'order' => 'ASC'
    )
);

// loop the results 
// This loops - across - the returned ids and passes ID's with children to the recursive function which iterates - down - that branch
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {

    $nav = '';
    $top_parent = 0;
    $processed = [];
    $page_ids = wp_list_pluck($query->posts, 'ID');

    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();

        // check if the pages parent is in the query results (it may have a parent, but not in the list)
        $parent_listed = in_array( $post->post_parent , $page_ids );

        // if the parent is not in the list it's a 'top level' page
        // top level pages only need to be handled separately if they dont have children, as those with children will be captured here when the child id is processed
        if( $parent_listed ) {
            
            // returns all ancestors. The top most one last in the array
            // we want to find the most senior ancestor that is also in the list
            $ancestors = get_post_ancestors( $post->ID );
            

            foreach($ancestors as $ancestor) {

                // returns false or key of listed ancestor
                $ancestor_listed = array_search( $ancestor , $page_ids );

                // the top level parent will be the last one looped 
                // must use strict comparison as key 0 is falsey. 
                if ($ancestor_listed !== false) {
                    // updates as the most senior ancestor listed is found
                    $top_parent = $page_ids[$ancestor_listed];
                }

            }

            // check if the top_parent has been processed before
            $parent_processed = in_array( $top_parent , $processed );

            // only process each top most parent once
            if ( !$parent_processed ) {

                // run the top parent through the recursive function
                // returns all children and grandchildren... of the top_parent
                $children = buildTree($page_ids, $top_parent, $current_page_id);
                
                // create html markup for parent item
                $nav .= '<li class="' .'page_item_'. $top_parent . ($children !== '' ? ' page_item_has_children':'') . ($top_parent == $current_page_id ? ' current_page_item':'') . (in_array($top_parent, $current_page_ancestors) ? ' current_page_ancestor':'') .'">';
                $nav .= '<a href="'. get_permalink($top_parent) .'"' . ($top_parent == $current_page_id ? 'aria-current="page"':'') . '>';
                $nav .= '<button class="expand-children"></button>';
                $nav .= get_the_title($top_parent);
                $nav .= '</a>';

                if ($children) {
                    // if there are children append them
                    $nav .= $children;
                }

                $nav .= '</li>';

                // add parent to processed array to keep track of them
                $processed[] = $top_parent;
                $top_parent = 0;

            }

        } else { 
            // if the page does not have a parent in the list, it is a top level item.
            // however we only need to handle it separatly if it does not have children in the list
            
            // check if the page has children. 
            // They may be in the list in which case it will be captured above. 
            $child_pages = get_pages( array('child_of'  => $post->ID) );

            if( $child_pages ) {

                $child_pages_listed = false;

                foreach( $child_pages as $page ) {

                // if it has children when need to check if they are in the list. 
                // They may not be if they have a different page template. 
                $is_listed = in_array( $page->ID , $page_ids );

                    if( $is_listed ) {

                        $child_pages_listed = $is_listed;
                    }

                }

                // if the page has children but they are not in the list, capture them here. 
                if( !$child_pages_listed ) {

                    $nav .= '<li class="' .'page_item_'. $post->ID . ($post->ID == $current_page_id ? ' current_page_item':'') . (in_array($post->ID, $current_page_ancestors) ? ' current_page_ancestor':'') .'">';
                    $nav .= '<a href="'. get_permalink($post->ID) .'"' . ($post->ID == $current_page_id ? 'aria-current="page"':'') . '>';
                    $nav .= '<button class="expand-children"></button>';
                    $nav .= esc_html( get_the_title() );
                    $nav .= '</a>';
                }

            } else { // if it does not have children then it is a top level page not capture above

                $nav .= '<li class="' .'page_item_'. $post->ID. ($post->ID == $current_page_id ? ' current_page_item':'') . (in_array($post->ID, $current_page_ancestors) ? ' current_page_ancestor':'') .'">';
                $nav .= '<a href="'. get_permalink($post->ID) .'"' . ($post->ID == $current_page_id ? 'aria-current="page"':'') . '>';
                $nav .= '<button class="expand-children"></button>';
                $nav .= esc_html( get_the_title() );
                $nav .= '</a>';
            }
            
        }

    }

    // if the branch is not empty wrap it in ul tags
    if($nav) {
        $nav = '<ul>' .$nav .'</ul>';
    }

    echo $nav;


    /* Restore original Post Data */
    wp_reset_postdata();

} else {
    // no posts found
}

 ?>
```